# got an unexpected keyword argumentというエラーメッセージ

Tags: python, python3

Google検索順位取得→エクセルに落とすというtoolをpythonで作っていますが、`got an unexpected keyword argument`というエラーメッセージがでてしまい、どうしてもうまく実行されません。

Excelファイル読み込みあたりのencodingのところで「予期しないキーワード引数」を受け取りましたと表示されなにか不具合が起きているのですが、自己解決ができませんでした。

どなたか教えていただければ幸いです。

## ソースコード

```
# coding:utf-8
import requests
import bs4
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

#出力データ
output_data = []
# output_data.append(['クエリ','検索順位', 'サイトtitle', 'サイトURL', '日付'])
today=datetime.date.today()#今日の日付

#検索順位取得処理
def search_url_google(search_url_keyword):
    if search_url_keyword and search_url_keyword.strip():
        #Google検索の実施
        search_url = 'https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&num=100&filter=0&q=' + search_url_keyword
        print("[INFO]Googleにアクセスしました")
        res_google = requests.get(search_url)
        print("[INFO]検索結果の取得に成功しました。")
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
        res_google.raise_for_status()
        #BeautifulSoupで掲載サイトのURLを取得
        bs4_google = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_google.text, 'html.parser')
        link_google = bs4_google.select('div > h3.r > a')

        for i in range(len(link_google)):
            #なんか変な文字が入るので除く
            site_url = link_google[i].get('href').split('&sa=U&')[0].replace('/url?q=', '')
            site_title=bs4_google.select('div > h3.r > a')[i].text#textで中身抽出。stringでもいいけどなぜかnoneが返る
            if 'https://' in site_url or 'http://' in site_url:
                #サイトの内容を解析
                try:
                    #print("[{}位:「{}」,URL「{}」]".format(i+1,site_title,site_url))
                    rank = i+1
                    title = site_title
                    URL = site_url

                    output_data_new = search_url_keyword, rank, title, URL, today
                    output_data.append(output_data_new)
                except:
                    continue



#CSVに書き出し
def csv_write():
    csv_file = open('[database].csv', 'a', encoding="utf_8_sig")
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator='\n')
    csv_writer.writerows(output_data)
    csv_file.close()


#Excelファイル読み込み
file = pd.read_excel('z.xlsx', encoding='utf8')
sheet_def = file.parse('Sheet1', header=None)
sheet_def = sheet_def[2:]
# 行ごとに処理
for i, row in sheet_def.iterrows():
    print('検索ワード:{}'.format(sheet_def.iat[i-2,1]))
    search_url_google(sheet_def.iat[i-2,1])
    sleep(2)
csv_write()
print("ok")#終わり
```

## エラーメッセージ

```
File "grc_test.py", line 57, in <module>
    sheet_def = file.parse('Sheet1', header=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

## 環境

python 3.7.3
pip 19.0.3

astroid==2.2.5
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.17
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==0.24.2
pylint==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.1
typed-ast==1.3.1
urllib3==1.24.1
wrapt==1.11.1
xlrd==1.2.0

Comment: 単純に encoding は外して、ファイル名指定だけで試してみては？

Comment: pandasや、その他利用中のパッケージのバージョンも記載するとより正確な回答が得られます。 `pip freeze` で確認出来るので編集して追記をお願いします。

Comment: パッケージのverを追記しました。

Comment: AttributeErrorということはは、メンバ変数かメンバ関数かにかかわらず「parse という attribute が存在しない」ことを言っているのか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandasのバージョンが記載されておりませんが、最新版（ `pandas 0.24.2` ）のリファレンスによると、そもそも `pandas.ExcelFile` で初期化時に直接ファイルパスを渡して読み込むという使い方が記載されておりません。

代わりに、 `pandas.read_excel` を使い、ファイルを読み込むのはいかがでしょうか。

[Input/Output — pandas 0.24.2 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html#excel)
[pandas.read_excel — pandas 0.24.2 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)

Answer (score -1):

エラーメッセージ読みましょう。
リファレンス読みましょう。
encoding引数が要らないのでは？